# how to skip reading rows if one of the values doesn't match the corresponding column type in org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena

I have created a table in Athena that gets data from gziped csv files inside folders from S3, with the following query:

```
CREATE external TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydatabase`.`mytable` (
  `messageId` string,
  `sourceCategory` string,
  `messageTime` string,
  `_messagetimepoch` string,
  `actallocmib` float,
  `activity` string,
  `bottom` integer,
  `numexecutions` integer,
  `numnodes` integer,
  `numprofilednodes` integer,
  `random` string,
  `tenantid` string,
  `usertime` integer,
  `version` string,
  `workunitduration` integer
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'separatorChar' = ',',
  'quoteChar' = '\"',
  'escapeChar' = '\\',
  'serialization.format' = ','
)
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3:location'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false',
  'compression.type'='gzip',
  'serialization.null.format'='',
  'skip.header.line.count'='1'
);
```

The table used to work properly till I got this error:

```
HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error reading field value: Cannot convert value "hostPid":9912} of type String to a REAL value
```

I tried adding this, in the SERDEPROPERTIES clause, but didn't work:

```
"ignore.malformed.json" = "true"
```

Anyone knows how to deal with this please ?
I want it to skip the entire row if one of the columns values, doesn't match that column type.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that there is one string in one of the fields defined as float (real) - most likely the field `actallocmib`.

As far as I know, there are no ways to fix that issue in the table definition.

Here few options:

1. You can define the field actallocmib as string, then in your query you can do this `try(cast(actallocmib as float))` that will return a null value for the faulty record
2. Consider to fix the issue in your gzipped csv and re-upload it fixing the data manually. - The error is also telling the line where there is the issue.

Based on your request, option 1 could seems the best.